# Yii2 ajax validation и загрузка файлов

Tags: ajax, yii2, валидация

Столкнулся с проблемой, валидация работает как надо, но только вот Yii2 при ajax валидации не отправляет сам файл, поэтому всегда получаю

> Загрузите файл.

P.S. Оставил бы валидацию на клиенте, но не знаю как прикрутить ее к динамически добавляемым полям, сейчас это работает так

```
$(document).on('click', '#add_file', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $('.file').length;

    file = '<div class="form-group field-file-img-'+id+'">';
    file += '<input type="hidden" name="File[img]['+id+']" value=""><input type="file" id="file-img-'+id+'" class="file" name="File[img]['+id+']">';
    file += '<div class="help-block"></div>';
    file += '</div>';

    $('.block_photo').append(file);

    var $form = $('#w0');

    $form.yiiActiveForm('add', {
        'id': 'file-img-'+id,
        'container': '.field-file-img-'+id,
        'input': '#file-img-'+id,
        enableAjaxValidation: true
    });
});
```

Как сделать на клиенте подобное, так и не разобрался :(

Comment: Добавьте форму, модель и контроллер которые обрабатывают загрузку файла. Правило валидации генерируется в зависимости от модели которую вы передаёте в ActiveForm, следовательно если вы создаёте поле динамически, его нет в сгенерированном скрипте.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем дважды тягать файл? Опустите проверку на обязательность файла при ajax валидации, через сценарии.